# How to restrict access to specific entities or properties in Cloud Datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

The [Identity and Access Management](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/access/iam) documentation for Datastore describes how to grant a user access to all entities. Is it possible to give a user access to certain entities or properties, but not others?

For example, given the entity 'Customer' with properties 'name', 'phone_number', and 'favorite_fruit', I would like to provide some users access to 'favorite_fruit', but not 'name' or 'phone_number'.

Is it possible to create permissions with this level of specificity? If not, how would you work around this limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the datastore itself has no such restriction mechanism in place, it's your app's responsability to enforce that. Even namespace enforcement is done in the app itself - by ensuring the proper namespace is specified when making the datastore calls.

End users don't typically have direct access to the datastore. The respective GCP project GAE apps and other apps which have been explicitly granted permissions have datastore-wide access and act as an intermediary between the end-user and the datastore. They're the ones enforcing the smaller scope access control.

The IAM doc you referenced reflects exactly that: datastore-wide scope, not an entity/property one.